# mysql return a fixed number of queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 mysql queries in php (one for each category/widget), all 3 queries together should output 3 * 6 = 18 results. So if one query returns less, more results from the other queries should be used.

How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Show sample data please and the ouput that you desire. It is also good if you show what query you have come up so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate 2 variables , keep count of selected rows and execute query using these counters

for example this will be your first query execiton

```
$default = 6;
$limit= $default;
$some_result = mysql("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $limit");
```

then you can use this for every query-limit

```
$limit = $limit - count($some_result) + $default;
```